# Formatting Table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to format a column in a table in a Shiny app but it is rendering as decimal.  Can anybody help me get the percentage formatting?  Here's my code:

Shiny Server code

```
output$freqTopCount =  DT::renderDataTable({
  freqTopCount <- faultCodeFrequency(Data, input$brwyline)
  freqTopCount[, input$brwyline] <- percent(freqTopCount[, input$brwyline])
  freqTopCount 
}, options = list(paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE)
, rownames = TRUE, caption = "Frequency")
```

Here's function being called

```
faultCodeFrequency <- function(FuncData, line) {
  FuncData <- as.data.frame(FuncData[which(FuncData[, 15] == line),])
  # Calculate frequency of fault codes by brewery line.
  freq <- as.data.frame(ungroup(mutate(summarise(group_by(FuncData, BRWYLine,Fault_Code), n = n()), freq = n / sum(n))))
  # Format frequency to 4 decimal points.
  freq$freq <- round(freq$freq,4)
  # Put the top 5 fault code frequencies by brewery line in a data table.
  freqTop <- data.table(freq)[order(freq, decreasing = TRUE), head(.SD, 5), by="BRWYLine"]
  # Remove column n from data table.
  freqTop$n <- NULL
  # Swing freqTop table into a crosstab. Brewery Line columns, Fault Code rows.  The sum function sums each combination of BrwyLine/FaultCode in the data table.
  freqTop <- tapply(freqTop$freq,list(freqTop$Fault_Code, freqTop$BRWYLine), FUN=sum)
  # Calculate sum of frequencies.
  freqTopSum <- as.matrix(t(colSums(freqTop,na.rm=TRUE)))
  # Name sum row.
  rownames(freqTopSum) <- ('Total')
  # Add sum row to frequency matrix.
  freqTopCount <- rbind(freqTop, freqTopSum)
  result <- freqTopCount
  result
}
```

Comment: did you already look in here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34728353/datatable-in-r-formatting-rows-with-specific-value-category-to-a-percentage

Comment: You can use `formatPercentage`, look [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html)

Comment: I used scales::percent() to solve my formatting problem.

Answer (score 1):

I used the percent() function in the scales package to solve this.

```
freqTopCount[, input$brwyline] <- scales::percent(freqTopCount[, input$brwyline])
```